# Codeigniter site wide views

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to implement advertisements in the sidebar of my codeigniter site.

The advertisements are dynamic and retrieved from the database. My current setup is I have  main template file, and I pass the name of the main view file to as a variable like below:

```
$data['main_content'] = 'some_view_file';
$this->load->view('template_file', $data);
```

I have thought of the following step:

1. Make a function `get_ads()` in my `MY_Controller` and retrieve all ads and return it
2. In each of my controller's method, I access the function created above and pass it to the template

```
$data['ads'] = $this->get_ads();
$data['main_content'] = 'some_view_file';
$this->load->view('template_file', $data);
```

But the problem with the above approach is, I need to set the `$data['ads'] = $this->get_ads();` in all of my methods before loading the view.

What would be a better way to handle the above problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a CodeIgniter Library called Ads.php

```
class Ads
{

    private $CI;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI = & get_instance();
    }

    public function my_ads()
    {
        // get the ads from database //
        return $this->CI->db->select('field1, field2, field3')->from('ads_table')->get()->result();
    }

}
```

Autoload the library (as you need ads in all views). Go to **./application/config/autoload.php**

```
/*
  | -------------------------------------------------------------------
  |  Auto-load Libraries
  | -------------------------------------------------------------------
  | These are the classes located in the system/libraries folder
  | or in your application/libraries folder.
  |
  | Prototype:
  |
  | $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'xmlrpc');
 */

$autoload['libraries'] = array('ads');
```

Now you can retrieve the data all over CI system using

```
$ads = $this->ads->my_ads();
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

In `MY_Controller` add a variable:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

      public $data;

      public function __construct() {
          $this->data['ads'] = $this->get_ads();      
          //etc.
      }
    //etc.
}
```

In each controller update the `$data` variable and call the view like this:

```
$this->data['main_content'] = 'some_view_file';
$this->load->view('template_file', $this->data);
```

Comment: I also assign titles, messages and other values in the `$data` variable. If I use the `$this->data`, I can think of some problems creeping up when I don't assign some values in some methods. Previously assigned values might be passed to the view file?  Instead, is it bad if I can use a `$this->ads` variable in my `MY_Controller` and access the `$this->ads` variable directly in the view files?

Comment: Where is the problem when you don't assign the values? If you don't assign a title in the controller and you don't call it in the view, there is no issue. You can use the `$this->ads` variable directly in the view if it simplifies things. It will be harder to maintain in the future because all the view's data is coming from the `$data` variable and this piece of data will be harder to trace.